# sshuffle off [scp] and [pscp]'s mortal coil

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Tags [scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scp) and [pscp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pscp) and [winscp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winscp) are tools which implement the file copying portion of the Secure Shell protocol (SSH).

There are a lot of questions about what SSH is, what SCP is and can do, and correct usage of these utilities, none of which are programming related.  And a few server-administration type questions about permission problems interfering with remote access.  Let the off-topic questions burn.

Then, there are questions about developing programs that wrap these utilities.  Those are on-topic, but should carry a tag related to spawning processes, such as [exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exec), [createprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/createprocess), [spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spawn).  And some care should be taken to weed out the former category disguised as a process spawning question... choosing command-line arguments for a utility is not a programming problem, but belongs on SuperUser or Unix & Linux SE.  The programming problems, related to automatically executing a command that is already working when typed manually, are independent of the command being executed, and so tagging by the command to spawn is quite useless.

Finally there may be a few questions about coding implementations of the protocol itself, which are on-topic and properly fall into [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh).

> Secure Shell - a network protocol for exchanging data throughout secure channel with most common uses of remote command execution (remote shell/console) and file transfer.

[ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh) also contains a bunch of off-topic questions as well, related to usage of the tools rather than developing them.  But at least the wiki-described scope is on-topic, so burnination isn't needed, just some spring cleaning.

[winscp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winscp) has scripting capability built in, so again there are some on-topic development questions using the tag, with a lot of usage questions mixed in.[filezilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filezilla) is essentially similar, although I'm not sure whether it has any plugin or scripting interface that would be on-topic; I see only off-topic questions.

Can anyone identify a legitimate need for separate tags [scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scp) and [pscp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pscp)?

---

I'm sure someone is going to defend these questions on the basis that they are "software tools commonly used by developers".  That's cherry-picking from the site scope.  Windows and Linux are also "commonly used by developers".  What the FAQ actually says:

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; **and is**
> - a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

That's a conjunction, not union.  All the usage questions fail the "unique to software development" requirement.  At least the ones I see when I browse the tag.  If you come up with examples of tool usage that really are specific to development, share them and let's think about whether the tags associated with the development task are sufficient or a tag is needed for the copy tool as well.

Comment: There's a lot here to read, but I agree with the core idea (these tags need cleaning, at the very least).